# debugging application in VS opened by doubleclick on file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

I´m working on a plugin for an existing application ( Autodesk Inventor ) using VS2012 & C#

I have a start action in my project properties that starts this application when debugging in VS, but how do I initiate debugging when the application is initiated by double clicking an application specific file through explorer.. I need debugging from the "start" as the initiation of the application in this manner is causing a bug in my plugin.

Comment: Windows Explorer starts the program associated with file type, and passes the file name as command-line parameter. Try to do set the same parameter in Visual Studio "Start Application" option.

Comment: I´m a numb on this.. What would the commandline parameter be for opening a specific file? A real NUMB...  WORKED.. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You create a temporary solution in Visual Studio with the .EXE.

1. File / Open Project.
2. Select EXE File.
3. In the Solution Explorer, right click the EXE to get the properties, and set the debug arguments as needed.
4. Debug.

Here are the complete instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0bxe8ytt.aspx